# Converting tuple into array and calling the new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I am developing custom regression analysis routine and ran into a problem trying to call tuple element for calculations:

```
EV = np.linalg.eig(xMe)
print EV
```

The result of print EV is below:

```
(array([  4.59554481e-02,   1.73592040e+04]), matrix([[-0.99977087, -0.02140571],
    [ 0.02140571, -0.99977087]]))
```

It is a tuple. I need to access each element in the first array in tuple ( 4.59554481e-02,   1.73592040e+04). When I try to convert tuple using:

```
lEV = np.asarray(EV)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-172-f46907801d9e> in <module>()
 42 print EV
 43 
---> 44 lEV = np.asarray(EV)

462     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
463 
464 def asanyarray(a, dtype=None, order=None):

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2)
```

I am new to Python and probably there is a very easy way to access these two elements but I can not figure it out.

Comment: Silly of me:)  It is easy: m= EV[0] and then call m[0] and m[1].  Any optimization suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pythonic way to do this would be to use tuple unpacking:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([[0,17],[42,23]])
>>> eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(a)
>>> print eigenvalues
array([-17.59037642,  40.59037642])

>>> print eigenvectors
array([[-0.69493692, -0.38630591],
       [ 0.71907071, -0.92237072]])
```

This allows you to unpack the two items of the tuple into two variables.
On those variables you can now use a standard for loop:

```
>>> for value in eigenvalues:
...    print(value)
-17.5903764156
40.5903764156
```

Alternatively (if you know how many values you will get) you can use tuple unpacking again:

```
>>> ev_1, ev_2 = eigenvalues
>>> print ev_1
-17.5903764156

>>> print ev_2
40.5903764156
```